# Setting up gitlint pre-commit local for a repository

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I am trying to add a gitlint pre-commit hook in a repository. The `.pre-commit-config.yaml` file looks lke this:

```
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: gitlint
        name: gitlint
        entry: gitlint
        language: system
```

However, I keep getting:

```
- hook id: gitlint
- exit code: 253

Usage: gitlint [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'gitlint --help' for help.

Error: No such command '.pre-commit-config.yaml'.
```

This is after I run:

```
pip install gitlint
pre-commit install --hook-type commit-msg
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How and where is `gitlint` installed?

Comment: installed on a MacOS. With pip install gitlint. 

I actually figured it out. I had to add `types: [python]` in the .pre-commit.yaml. Now I have a different problem. I will update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration is broken because of a few reasons:

- you've configured `gitlint` for all `stages`, meaning it will run on other git hooks you don't want (such as `pre-commit`, `pre-push`, etc.). to fix this you'll set `stages: [commit-msg]`
- you're missing a few other settings as well such as the proper arguments to `gitlint` etc.
- additionally you're using `language: system` which means you're depending on your contributors to set up tooling -- this **misses the point of pre-commit** and is the unsupported escape hatch.  the usual way to have managed tools is to reuse an existing repository (see below) or to use `additional_dependencies` to install the tool in a managed way

The supported way to use gitlint is from the repository itself

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: https://github.com/jorisroovers/gitlint
    rev: ''  # pick a tag / sha to use
    hooks:
    -   id: gitlint
```

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit and contributed the pre-commit support to gitlint

Comment: Thanks. That was very helpful. I still want to set it up locally and so I did. Your comments helped me to it.

Comment: i am sorry i still dont get it even after reading the documentation on pre-commit.com what is the difference between language python and language system. Docs say "This hook type will not be given a virtual environment to work with " what happens if you set language python? does it automatically pick poetry from the pyproject.toml file to find out dependencies?

Comment: @PirateApp did you read [this](https://pre-commit.com/#python) ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is not very helpful. I was just missing args and stages fields:

```
# See https://pre-commit.com for more information
# See https://pre-commit.com/hooks.html for more hooks
---
repos:
   - repo: local
     hooks:
       - id: gitlint
         name: gitlint
         language: python
         entry: gitlint
         args: [--staged, --msg-filename]
         stages: [commit-msg]
```